# Odd $_SERVER values over ssl

Tags: php, apache, ssl, https, get

I am experiencing a strange issue whereby I am getting incorrect query string values after calling back to a secure (https://) page on my site, from a secure payment gateway.  Here's the contents of PHP's `$_SERVER` variable:

```
Array
(
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.4.9 (Unix)
    [REQUEST_URI] => /sign-up/?gfsagepay_return=bGVhZF9pZD0yMDE5Jmhhc2g9ZWZlNWI3ZmIxNjVhNDVkZmIzMDY2ODBiMzcwOThhZjY
    [PATH] => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [UNIQUE_ID] => VE50xX8AAAEAABWSAuMAAAAh
    [HTTPS] => on
    [SCRIPT_URL] => /sign-up/
    [SCRIPT_URI] => http://www.domain.co.uk/sign-up/
    [HTTP_HOST] => www.domain.co.uk
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_REFERER] => https://live.sagepay.com/gateway/service/cardselection?vpstxid={08D220FE-1BD0-0B60-4670-A359B31465B4}
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip,deflate,sdch
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8
    [HTTP_COOKIE] => wp-settings-5=editor%3Dtinymce%26libraryContent%3Dbrowse; wp-settings-time-5=1413364146; wordpress_test_cookie=WP+Cookie+check; wordpress_logged_in_0293e473decb4ad0ae4f16569dce74a6=matt%7C1414580241%7Ccc0bdf718d4ab94b2cd21206b75ed52a; _gat=1; C4ATBCookie380b0a7e-5814-4897-a71d-e720dca390b7_Cook_VisitorID=d40f8cd2-bd27-4c21-a2bd-83dab0637710; C4ATBCookie380b0a7e-5814-4897-a71d-e720dca390b7_Cook_DTS=27/Oct/14%2016%3A32%3A57; C4ATBCookie380b0a7e-5814-4897-a71d-e720dca390b7_Cook_ServerGUID=5B1C1DCB-07EA-45E1-91C7-BDC96AF8EE98; C4ATBCookie380b0a7e-5814-4897-a71d-e720dca390b7_Cook_Visits=6; C4ATBCookie380b0a7e-5814-4897-a71d-e720dca390b7_Cook_ExtSets=27/Oct/14%2016%3A32%3A57%7Chttps%3A//prod3si.click4assistance.co.uk%7Chttps%3A//prod3ci.click4assistance.co.uk%7CTrue%7CTrue%7CFalse%7CTrue%7CTrue%7C5%7C10%7C20%7CTrue%7CTrue%7CFalse%7C30; _ga=GA1.3.1269087434.1413364095; C4ATBCookie380b0a7e-5814-4897-a71d-e720dca390b7C4ATBTestP=Y
    [HTTP_X_PROTO] => SSL
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => close
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => <address>Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) Server at www.crb-checkonline.co.uk Port 80</address>

    [SERVER_NAME] => www.domain.co.uk
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 10.0.1.55
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => 81.152.144.31
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/sites/domain.co.uk/public_html
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /home/sites/domain.co.uk/public_html
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => root@localhost
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /home/sites/domain.co.uk/public_html/index.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 34353
    [REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => /sign-up/
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /sign-up/
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => /sign-up/
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1414427845
)
```

I am expecting the `QUERY_STRING` value to be:

```
gfsagepay_return=bGVhZF9pZD0yMDE5Jmhhc2g9ZWZlNWI3ZmIxNjVhNDVkZmIzMDY2ODBiMzcwOThhZjY
```

but instead it is:

```
/sign-up/
```

The contents of `$_GET` confirm this oddity:

```
Array
(
    [/sign-up/] => 
)
```

I am also surprised that the `REQUEST_SCHEME` value is `http` and not `https`, although I have read that this is not always reliable.

Does this look like an SSL misconfiguration, or could something else in my script be affecting it?

Regards,

Matt.

PS. For reference, the root .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [PT,L]

Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Probably you are not passing `GET` parameters in your apache `rewrite` rules since the `REQUEST_URI` seems correct.

Comment: Thanks @Kypros, I have added my .htaccess to the question. But if the callback URL is already https:// then it wouldn't be redirected anyway, right?  Also, I was under the impression that a [R] redirect included the query string by default, so [QSA] isn't required?

Comment: Not sure about this but i think you do need `QSA` as well for the parameters to follow after the redirect

Comment: @Kypros, I just tried adding QSA but it didn't make any difference I'm afraid.